# CSS - Simple specificity issue - '#div-id ul' - won't override list-style of 'ul'

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

This is a very simple issue of CSS specificity, but I really can't figure it out somehow.

In my stylesheet, I have a simple rule that removes the list-style from lists:

```
ul { list-style: none; }
```

Then, for some lists, I would like to specify a list-style, but no matter what, it just won't override the above rule?

```
#product ul { list-style: bullet !important; }
```

The problem is that the UL will often be entered into a WYSIWYG box in a CMS and I don't want to force the user to have to write in html and give the UL a specific ID, so we will often end up with code such as:

```
<div id="product">
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm a little surprised this just isn't working, is there no way to remedy this other than using javascript to give $('#product ul') a specific class or css style?

--

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/ohuzuz/4

--

EDIT: Oops, sorry, I had:

```
<div id="#product">
```

a temporary mistake that was in the jsbin, but not my original code. My mistake, but the problem was indeed the invalid

```
list-style: disc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bullet` is not a valid list-style-type value.

Also, if that isn't the issue, check if you don't have `li` styled anywhere. Styles for `li` elements override those for `ul` elements, no matter the specificity.

Comment: Mr Lister nails it. The [possible `list-style-types` are disc, circle, square, decimal, etc., but no "bullet"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type)

Comment: Oh goodness, I'm sorry. I am far too tired. This was definitely the issue, the invalid list-style-type. Thankyou!

Comment: But the ones who complain about `id="#product"` are right too!

Comment: Yes definitely, but I made that mistake accidentally in the jsbin, but not in my original code.

Answer (score 4):

Your ID is wrong

change:

```
id="#product"
```

to:

```
id="product"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is correct code. You have wrong id #product should be product in your div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }

  ul { list-style: none; }

  #product ul, #product ul li { list-style: disc; }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p id="hello">Hello World</p>
  <div id="product">
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something like this,

```
ul { list-style:none; }
#product ul {list-style:disc inside none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an extra character in your html

`<div id="#product">`

Remove the `#` and it should work.